# Change relative link paths for included content in PHP

Tags: php, url, include, relative-path

I have a PHP file at my server root.. **index.php** .. which [`include`](http://www.php.net/include/)'s .. DIR/**main.php**

Now .. DIR/**main.php** ..  has relative links to many nearby files.

All the relative links are broken.

---

Any way I can change the relative-URL base path **for links?**

... so the included content of  DIR/**main.php** has all its links to **friend1.php** changed to **DIR/friend1.php**.

---

Edit: This in NOT about include's, this is about CHANGING ahref links en-masse.

Comment: Downvoted because you don't understand?

Comment: Is it feasible to do a search and replace on the entire project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **base** tag in html works for relative links. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) for an example on how to use it.

Comment: The base tag requires an absolute path. And is no longer properly supported in Internet Explorer, since version 7.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming main.php is a mix of HTML and PHP then when you output a link you'll need to include a prefix:

```
<a href="<?php echo $web_root; ?>relative/path/">relative link</a>
```

Where $web_root is your root path ('DIR'). Probably a good idea to define it in a separate include file so you only have to define it once for all your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The picture isn't too clear but you can probably rearrange a few files and use symlinks to solve the problem.

For your example, you could make a symlink DIR/friend1.php that points to /friend1.php, but you would have to do this for all your files, or just move them.