# How to handle included links in PHP?

Tags: php, include

I want to include a menu in my php pages. Like this:

in index.php

```
require_once 'includes/menu.php';
```

in dir/index.php

```
require_once 'includes/menu.php';
```

in menu.php I have:

```
<a href='link1.php'>Link 1</a>
<a href='link2.php'>Link 2</a>
<a href='link3.php'>Link 3</a>
```

The problem is that the path should be different for the subdirectory and the root.
How I can handle this, so that the output is **link1.php** for the index, and **../link1.php** for the sub directories?

**I found this link, but the question is not very clear, so I don´t known if is related:** [Change relative link paths for included content in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579565/change-relative-link-paths-for-included-content-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one thought: use absolute paths. Putting the href as `/link1.php` will link to `http://www.yourdomain.com/link1.php`, regardless of what subdirectory one is in.

Since I don't know the particulars of your situation, however, that may not be an acceptable solution. Just putting it out there.

If your menu is used in different subdirectories to actually refer to different locations, however, e.g. used at `/foo/sub/index.php` to refer to `/foo/link1.php` and also used at `/bar/sub/index.php` to refer to `/bar/link1.php`, then the [HTML base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) might come in handy.

Comment: @Matchu: A logical choice, any other idea?

Comment: @Edgar: an HTML solution is likely far cleaner than any sort of PHP solution one could hack together, I bet. If this menu is reused in multiple subdirectories, however, making your menu uncertain of what the absolute path would be, the HTML [base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag might be helpful.

Comment: -1: not a good solution for writing a portable application (i.e. which might not always be in the same place relative the document root

Comment: @symcbean: that's why I mentioned the base tag in the comments, for that situation exactly :) It's also why I pointed out that, though absolute paths are the best solution, it may not work for him. I've added the base tag to the main answer, however, for good measure.

Comment: I'm not that great of a PHP programmer but I've had to use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` in addition to the file path. Anyone else?

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago for the files it's okay. But it's useless for the urls.

Comment: @symcbean Think of it as of desired result. In HTML, it should be absolute path. and you can get it by various ways - with PHP helper or without it. @Matchu have you ever used base tag yourself?

Comment: @symcbean, @Matchu: I've never used <base> before. A new trick to learn, thanks to both.

Comment: @Edgar just keep not using it. It's a trap, not trick. Define all your paths explicitly.

Comment: If I use absolute paths, it will affects the testing in local environment.

Comment: @Edgar: I usually simplify this sort of thing by setting up a local domain, adding an entry in the hosts file, and setting up a virtual host in Apache. It can take a bit to set up the first time, but for long-term projects, it saves a ton of effort.

Comment: @Edgar you didn't get the whole point. Blame symcbean for this. God, this site produce lamers in great numbers.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: After reading some issues with the base tag, I´m not sure it is a good choice (example: http://mondaybynoon.com/2006/11/13/the-pros-and-cons-of-the-base-tag/). I think I´m going to stay with absolute paths, if no other option arises.

Comment: @Edgar absolute paths is the only solution. open this very page source for example. all local resources using absolute paths. There are many ways to achieve it, but in the resulting HTML it should be regular absolute path. That's like street addresses. "Some street, building 8" will be always the same from anywhere, but "next house to the left" depends on your current position. What would you write on a letter? If the first one - why so much fear for the absolute path on the website?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend defining a 'base' URL as part of the application config and prefixing any links with that.

(NB you can caclulate the base url at run time - but need different logic for different parts of the app - unless the 'root' directory of your app is always constant, e.g.

```
function get_app_root($fromthis)
{
   if (basename(fromthis)=='myapproot') {
       return $fromthis;
   }
   if (dirname($fromthis)=='') {
       return false;
   }
   return get_app_root(dirname($fromthis));
}

$appbase=get_app_root(__FILE__);
if ($appbase===false) {
    die "Whoops!";
}
```

(would need a few tweaks to handle URLs rather than paths)

Comment: A clean answer when absolute paths won't do it :) +1

Comment: I'm confused by the code sample, though. Could you include an example of its use? It looks like it tracks back to a known directory name. If one knows the app root, why calculate it? It sounds like it'd just be a matter of setting `/mysubdir/` as the application root, and prefixing it to all URLs.

Comment: Man, you spoiled your whole answer. What is this ugly code for?