# Web development - relative URLs without duplicating files

Tags: php, include, relative-path, relative-url

I have a site with `index.php` in the root folder, images in `/img` , and `overview.php` in `/content`. I have a `sidebar.php` file that is included in both `index.php` and `overview.php`. How should I refer to `/img/image.gif` if I include a link in each file?
The location of `image.gif` changes relative to the location of the file that references it.
Using `/img/image.gif` in `sidebar.php` will work in `index.php`, but it fails for the file located at `/content/overview.php`.
The only solution that I can see is to either include a separate `sidebar.php` in each sub-directory, or include an `/img` directory in every sub-directory.
The best suggestion that I can find is to use the `<base`> HTML tag as suggested here:
[Change relative link paths for included content in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579565/change-relative-link-paths-for-included-content-in-php/579746#579746)

However, in the same link, SamGoody suggests that the `<base`> tag **`is no longer properly supported in Internet Explorer, since version 7.`**

I'd like some insight on the matter before committing to a course of action.

Thanks.

EDIT: I am using the wrong approach below with `"../"`

Example-

root/index.php:

```
...  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />  
<title>title</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<?php include('include/header.php'); ?>  
<?php include('include/menu.php'); ?>
...
```

root/include/header.php:

```
...  
<div id="header">  
<span class="fl"><img src="img/dun1.png"/></span><span class="fr"><img src="img/dun2.png"/></span> 
...
```

root/content/overview.php:

```
...  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css" media="screen" />  
<title>Overview</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<?php include('../include/header.php'); ?>
<?php include('../include/menu.php'); ?>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using /img/image.gif in sidebar.php will work in index.php, but it fails for the file located at /content/overview.php

But it shouldn't. The preceding `/` makes it an absolute path which will work from any point on the server. If this doesn't work for you, there's a problem somewhere - in that case, post some examples.

Unless you are planning to move the whole site into a sub-directory one day, or move images to a Content Delivery Network (both actions would require re-writing the addresses) you can safely use absolute URLs.

Comment: thanks, that's helped clarify some things for me. I've tried / and ../ , but cannot get it to work. If I change "style.css" to "/root/style.css" in overview.php I do get the style, but I cannot apply the same idea to images. Using "/root/" is probably a poor choice for this example as it is not the root of my localhost. The "/root" I refer to is located at "var/www/root"  I'm guessing it's something I don't know about relative/absolute paths, or something I don't know about php includes, or my apache server is misconfigured, or all of the above.

Comment: @eshriek what is your Apache web root? `www` or `root`?

Comment: I think I have it figured out. I've moved everything to apache web root (www). In "[www]/index.php" I have "style.css" and "include/header.php" whereas in "[www]/content/overview.php" I use "/style.css" and "../include/header.php". I don't think this is ideal, but it works. I'm just afraid I may run into problems when I upload it to the actual server.